# How can I make a variable inside a test for null available outside of the block?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (question.DetailsJSON != null) {
   var details = JSON.FromJSONString<List<Question.Detail>>(question.DetailsJSON);
}
```

This works but outside of the block the details is not available.

Without pre-declaring the details variable is there a way that I could do this if test and still have details available once outside of the if ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the declaration and initialization, and use a conditional operator to avoid introducing a new scope with the `if` statement:

```
var details = question.DetailsJSON != null
?   JSON.FromJSONString<List<Question.Detail>>(question.DetailsJSON)
:   null;
```

Comment: Just remeber, you will still have to test for null then on details later when used.